# Can a VM be the default OS from GRUB for a second User?

Tags: boot, grub2, virtualbox, users

I want to create a VM with a kid friendly distro for my 2 kids (almost 4 and almost 5) on my pc.  Is it possible to use this VM as the default OS when they log in under their user?  Or will it need to be something that I open for them every time they log in.

I am new to Linux, never created a dual boot (although I am interested in it), never created a VM, etc.  I want to convert an older but descent (1TB hard drive and an Intel i5) pc from Windows 7 to Ubuntu Mate for myself for my new adventure into learning to write code AND create a VM of Edubuntu for my kids and their development in education and technology.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you can dual boot of Ubuntu Mate and Edubuntu that will do the job as your expect but we cannot change os by switching users. Virtual box creates a new OS that needs to be started after logging in it is type 2 hyper visor that means that it needs a host os and a guest os.  I guess easiest solution will be for your children create new user in Ubuntu Mate then create a startup script to launch virtual box os.

Comment: `VBoxManage list vms` will list all the vms available.
`VBoxManage startvm "My Ubuntu"` can start ubuntu from virtual box. 
You can create a start up application for this command.

Comment: This is great and exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you MinusInfinity.  This is a great head start to get me going and  pointed me in the right direction to research how to create the startup script.